# Moving rails from to from _form.html.erb to application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have most of the functionality done for a site. Now I am trying to make it look nice. I have a _form.html.erb that works great.

```
<%= form_for(@card) do |f| %>
<% if @card.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@card.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this card from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
    <% @card.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :event %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :event %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Files

```
view
- cards
-- new.html.erb
-- index.html.erb
-- show.html.erb
- layouts
-- application.html.erb
- pages
-- index.html.erb
```

I make a call for the form from new.html.erb and it works sends it to show.html.erb, just as I want. I'm using bootstrap and decided to make use of the nav bar. I have placed the nav bar code into the application.html.erb. It works just fine, well kind of. I want what would normally be a search function to be the add a new card.

When I add the form call it does not work, when I add it directly to the application page it does not work. I'm not sure, I have spent hours on this. I got it to work only on the show.html.erb page, both index pages would error out. I honestly don't remember how I did this though.

I'm trying to learn by doing, but I am stuck and need some help.

Thank you,
    Ian

Answer (score 1):

I guess that when you say that its working in your new.html.erb you have a `new` action inside your `cards_controller`, and inside this action you have something like: `@card = Card.new`

Well, if you want to put this form in another view, like in the application.html.erb you need to set first your @card variable, so you can do something like:

```
# application_controller:
before_filter :new_card
def new_card
  @card = Card.new
end
```

be aware that all the controller that inherits from application controller will set this @card variable

Answer (score 0):

**@instance_variable**

The underlying problem here is that you're calling a [**partial**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) - by design, these are meant to give you the ability to call the functionality the file contains *anywhere* in your application

The problem you have is  you're referencing an *`@instance_variable`* directly in your partial.

This isn't normally an issue - if you're using partials like you were originally (to modularize views), it should be okay. The problems arise when you try and use the partials in a more generalized way, as you are doing now:

```
#app/views/controller/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@card) do |f| %>
```

This relies on the `@card` instance variable being made available, which won't be if you're loading the partial in any other controller than the `cards_controller`.

--

**Fix**

The way to fix this is to either populate the `@card` instance variable in the application controller (as described by `edymerchk`), or to pass the raw value through the `locals` hash of the `partial` call:

This will allow you to use the `card` *local variable* in your partial:

```
#app/views/controller/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for card do |f| %>
```

-

Alternatively, you could also set the `@card` instance variable, as recommended in another answer:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_card

   private

   def set_card
      @card = Card.new
   end
end
```